# Error when linking GSL with -static

Tags: g++, static-linking, archlinux, gsl

I have written a programm in c++. Linking and runiing is working, as long as I don't use the "-static" option for g++. But I have to run it from an Antergos USB-Live Stick with default settings and there is no GSL included. In the manual of GSL they recommend

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ -static main.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lnlopt
```

But for this code I receive an error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als End-Status zurück
```

I tried it as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181154/linking-gsl-or-other-library-statically-into-a-shared-library#3181246), but it didn't work for me. When I run

```
$ g++ -O2 -o test main.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lnlopt -lm
$ lld test
```

it prints

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa5b95000)
libgsl.so.19 => /usr/lib/libgsl.so.19 (0x00007f8748c9a000)
libgslcblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0 (0x00007f8748a5d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f87486d5000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f87483d1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f87481ba000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8747e1c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f87490fe000)
```

So I tried to create a symlink, but I do have also "libgsl.so"

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libgsl
libgslcblas.so        libgslcblas.so.0.0.0  libgsl.so.19          
libgslcblas.so.0      libgsl.so             libgsl.so.19.3.0
```

Am I doing something stupid? Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `-lgsl`, by default you request the linker to
find and link either the shared library `libgsl.so` or the static
library `libgsl.a` and to prefer the shared library, if both are found
in the same search directory. The linker will search, first, in any
directories you have specified with the `-L/path/to/search` options,
in the order you specified, and then in its default search directories
(`/usr/lib`, etc.). Likewise for `-lgslcblas`.

But when you pass the linkage option `-static` to `gcc/g++`, it prevents
linking with any shared libraries. Shared libraries, `libgsl.so`, `libgslcblas.so`
will be ignored. Static libraries `libgsl.a`, `libgslblas.a`, must be
found, in some or other of the search directories, for the linkage to
succeed.

The linker is saying:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
```

because it can't find those static libraries - presumably because you
haven't installed them.

You do not say what linux distro you are working on, but if the package
that provides `libgsl` and `libgslcblas` is called, say, `libgsl[suffix]`
then there will be a corresponding package called `libgsl-dev`, `libgsl-devel`,
or similar. This will be the *development* version of the package,
for the use of people who want to develop software that links with `libgsl`
or `libgslcblas`. The development package will require the `libgsl` package as a dependency
- so it will install the same stuff - and will in addition contain the
library's header files *and the static version of the library*.

So you need to install the `libgsl` development package for your distro.
For Ubuntu, for example, that is `libgsl-dev`:

**Later**

I gather that your distro, Arch Linux, does not do separate dev packages. You
need to build the static libraries from source. To do that you will need
at least to have installed:

```
GNU Make
GNU autotools (autoconf, automake, libtool)
GCC (C compiler)
texinfo
```

Then to make a default build:

- Get the gsl source package from `https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=gsl`
  either by cloning the git repo or downloading a current `tar.gz` tarball
  and extracting it.
- `cd` into the package directory.
- run `./autogen.sh`. This will succeed provided the GNU autotools prerequisites
  are fulfilled.
- run `./configure --enable-maintainer-mode` (as `./autogen.sh` will have prompted you).
  This will succeed provided that the package dependencies are satisfied
  and environment sanity checks pass.
- run `make`
- If `make` completes without errors - which will take a matter of minutes -
  then, *as root*, run `make install`.

If all is well, this will install your missing static libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.a
/usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.a
```

You should not need to modify your linkage command for the linker to find
them: `/usr/local/lib` is a default linker search path.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. It's true, I don't have `libgsl.a`. I have Arch Linux, and therefore I have installed _gsl 2.3-1_.  But the repository don't have any development package. Can you tell me if [this page](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=gsl) is the correct one?

Comment: @D.Nagel From [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28972/why-are-there-no-dev-packages-in-arch-linux)
it appears that Arch Linux doesn't do separate dev packages and if static libs aren't
in the stock package, you'll have to build them yourself from source. Your
link is correct to get the source either from the git repo or in a `tar.gz`.
The source package is a GNU autotools package. Do you know how to build those?

Comment: I tried it, but no I dont know. I downloaded _release-2.3_, but it didn't contain a _configure_ file only a _configure.ac_. When I'm running `autoconf configure.ac` I receive some error.
`configure.ac:6: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`
`configure.ac:8: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_MAINTAINER_MODE`

Comment: @D.Nagel Updated answer may help